# PHP: Trouble getting all possible results from Google Maps API

Tags: php, google-maps, geocoding

I've recently noticed certain nuances when using Google Maps API to help in a site I'm developing. Specifically, I've noticed that Google Maps will only return a single location in instances where multiple locations should have been returned.

Examples, [Whitfield](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Whitfield&sensor=false)
in Google Maps returns 10 places, which is fine.

But, [Gulf Port](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Guild%20Port&sensor=false)
returns 1 place in IL, even though it should be returning another place in Florida as well ( [Gulf Port, FL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Guild%20Port,%20FL&&sensor=false)
).

Likewise, [Saint Petersburg](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Saint%20Petersburg&sensor=false)
 returns 1 place in Russia, even though it should be returning another place in Florida as well ( [Saint Petersburg, FL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Saint%20Petersburg,%20FL&sensor=false)
).

How can I get google to return ALL of the locations that it should be listing, 100% of the time? Is there an argument I need to use? I've taken a look at the 'bounds' arg which I thought I could perhaps use to get all results by 
[setting the bounds to encompass the entire world](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Saint%20Petersburg&sensor=true&bounds=-180,180|180,-180)
, but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: Just tested again with Birmingham and it just brings up Birmingham, Alabama, neglecting Birmingham in the United Kingdom. [link] (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=birmingham&sensor=false) `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=birmingham&sensor=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it would appear that the api for googlemaps has a region bias that, even when turned off or left unspecified, will return certain results and not include others. This explains the issues I faced with countries that share the same name, but does not explain at all instances like the Gulf Port issue which I mentioned.

I've concluded that the only solution is to specify a city, state / province.